# Cant deploy flask app to heroku due to some dependency issue with scipy?

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I am trying to deploy a simple "hello world" app in flask to heroku. Here is the code for the app itself (its named hello.py):

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__=="__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Here is the procfile:

```
web: gunicorn hello:app
```

When I try to deploy my app with the windows command prompt, it fails. I have extracted the part of the output which I think is relevant

```
remote:          Running setup.py install for Werkzeug
remote:
remote:
remote:          Running setup.py install for scipy
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-oRWdEw/scipy/setup.py", line 237, in <
module>
remote:                setup_package()
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-oRWdEw/scipy/setup.py", line 225, in s
etup_package
remote:                from numpy.distutils.core import setup
remote:            ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core
remote:            Complete output from command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -
c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-oRWdEw/scipy/setup.py';e
xec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n
'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-_HDaE9-record/install-record.t
xt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-oRWdEw/scipy/setup.py", line 237, in <
module>
remote:
remote:                setup_package()
remote:
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-oRWdEw/scipy/setup.py", line 225, in s
etup_package
remote:
remote:                from numpy.distutils.core import setup
remote:
remote:            ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core
remote:
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:            Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c "import setuptools
, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-oRWdEw/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(
tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'
))" install --record /tmp/pip-_HDaE9-record/install-record.txt --single-version-
externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-oRWdEw/
scipy
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to cs242-chaya2-final.
remote:

Warning: Your console font probably doesn't support Unicode. If you experience s
trange characters in the output, consider switching to a TrueType font such as L
ucida Console!
To https://git.heroku.com/cs242-chaya2-final.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/cs242-chaya2-final.gi
t'

(venv) C:\Users\Kamal\Documents\School\Spring2015\CS242\cs242-chaya2-final>
```

I think the numpy.distutils.core is causing the error, I am not sure how to fix this though, can anyone help me out?

here is my requirements.txt:

```
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
elasticsearch==1.4.0
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Login==0.2.11
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
numpy==1.6.2
scipy==0.14.0
urllib3==1.10.2
virtualenv==12.0.7
Werkzeug==0.10.1
```

Comment: Put your requirements.txt here

Comment: beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
elasticsearch==1.4.0
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Login==0.2.11
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
numpy==1.6.2
scipy==0.14.0
urllib3==1.10.2
virtualenv==12.0.7
Werkzeug==0.10.1

Comment: If you are hosting simple helloword, why these all requirements ?

Comment: This is what the pip freeze command generated, I did not make this. Are you saying its ok to delete some of them?

Comment: No need of all these.Create a new `vitualenv` and install flask, then pip freeze

Comment: Heroku doesn't let you use Scipy directly in heroku. Read my question and tell me if you're having the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104827/deploying-flask-app-using-python-3-5-and-scipy-on-heroku