# Deploying Flask App using Python 3.5 and Scipy on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, scipy, buildpack

I'm try to use create a flask web app on Heroku that uses python 3.5, scipy and flask.

It's well known I suppose that Heroku (still) can't install scipy on its platform. I'm wondering if anyone knows how to push a Flask app to Heroku that can use scipy. I know there are buildpacks that exist (like this one `https://github.com/kennethreitz/conda-buildpack`) but they don't use the version of python I would like **and** doesn't seem to let gunicorn and flask do there web app thing.

I don't know if that's clear enough so comment if there's anyway I can make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** I had to make a new buildpack that I will maintain since the one that I had previously was changed and now only supports *Python 2.7*. Mine supports *Python 3*.

Here's step by step what you should do.

1) Add this https://github.com/arose13/conda-buildpack.git to your `BUILDPACK_URL`

2) Create a `conda-requirements.txt` with all your requirements that you need anaconda to get, here is where you include python version 3 and scipy. This can be done in command-line with...

`conda list -e > conda-requirements`

3) Order matters in the `conda-requirements.txt`. It should look like this...

```
numpy=1.10.1
scipy=0.16.0
```

4) `requirements.txt` contains all the requirements that you want `pip` to install. You can use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` Just make sure that there's nothing on this list that is on the `conda-requirements.txt` list.

5) Push to Heroku.

PS: github project example is here https://github.com/arose13/HerokuCondaScipyFlaskApp

Comment: Great example! Worked for me. Didn't know the order in the requirements file matters.

Comment: It works great. Does it need to be conda-requirements.txt or can it also accepts the environment.yml file format?